# Retrieve Facebook Page wall posts

Tags: facebook, access-token

I want to include the FB Page wall into the website. For that purpose I need the access token, but on the FB I'm one of the admins not the owner.

When I request an access token I get one of my profile not the profile that I´m administrating. Can I get a token for that wall as admin and not owner ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ you can see there are options to log in as an App or as a Page: those should give you an access token that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

From: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

"Page access_token

An access_token used to manage a page. This is used when you want to perform an operation acting as a Page. This access token is retrieved by issuing an HTTP GET to /USER_ID/accounts or to /PAGE_ID?fields=access_token with the **manage_pages** permission. Getting /USER_ID/accounts will return a list of Pages (including app profile pages) to which the user has administrative access in addition to an access_token for each Page. NOTE: After September 22, 2011, manage_pages permission will be required for all access to a user's pages via this connection, i.e. for both reading the user's pages and also retrieving access_tokens for those pages. See the documentation for the User object for more information."

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has [extended](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/524/) their `page` object to make it easier to retrieve a "page" `access_token", what you need is:

- manage_pages & read_stream [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)
- the page_id
- Something like the code in my [article](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-post-on-facebook-page-as-page-not-as-admin-user-using-php-sdk/31/):

P.S: I'm using the PHP-SDK

```
<?php
// This code is just a snippet of the example.php script
// from the PHP-SDK <http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php>
require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'app_id',
  'secret' => 'app_secret',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $page_id = 'page_id';
    $page_info = $facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");
    if( !empty($page_info['access_token']) ) {
        $args = array(
            'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token']
        );
        $page_posts = $facebook->api("/$page_id/posts","get",$args);
    }
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'manage_pages,read_stream'));
}
?>
```